# How do I browse the local directory's files without using OpenFileDialog? (C#)

Tags: c#, directory, browser, openfiledialog

I want to build something where the user to browse the local files on the application I am providing, the screen is actually identical to OpenFileDialog, but I do not want that to be a dialog but a control on my form.

I tried to use a Web Browser control, it works, but I have to write a bunch of navigation code in order for that to work, and another problem is if the user selected any files on that screen, I am not sure how to capture the results.

So is there another way to do that? Or maybe override some of the OpenFileDialog control to make it not only showing as a dialog but a normal control.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this is what you are looking for:

It uses the tree view.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/TreeViewFileExplorer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the openfiledialog and attempt to ownerdraw that (which I think you can enable).

Answer (score 0):

Use controls from [Shell MegaPack](http://www.ssware.com/megapack.htm) - they can be put on your own forms, and provide lots of customization and flexibility.

DISCLAIMER: I work for LogicNP Software, the developer of Shell MegaPack.